# sitecore 8.1: on selecting condition link in personalization throwing 'element is Empty' exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to set rationalization rule for an item, by going through the item presentation-->details-->controllers-->select controller-->personalize-->create condition-->add rule on click of the condition link getting `element is null` exception. Below is the details I see in the logs:

```
Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: element is null
Source: Sitecore.Client
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Rules.RulesEditor.RulesEditorPage.Edit(String uid, String name, String control, String parameters)



ManagedPoolThread #15 16:12:45 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #15 16:12:45 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #13 16:13:00 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #13 16:13:00 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
10172 16:13:04 FATAL [Experience Analytics]: ReduceAgent can't execute. No sites found
```

[image: Screenshot for the same]

Comment: Can you check if your Website\App_Browsers has files, and what are the names of these files?

Comment: Hey Mohammed, Later i fixed this issue, yes you're correct i was missing assp_browser folder in the file structure, once i added it, it was started working. anyhow thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: I will add this as answer, mark it as answer if this is fixed you problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to missing files from the following path:
Website\App_Browser\

Following are the missing files names:

- Form.browser
- XamlPage.browser